# Get keyboard's superview in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, keyboard

I am trying to move keyboard with the uiviewcontroller when the user is trying to go back using edge swipe and keyboard is there on the controller. 
So one solution I found is to animate keyboard's superview along with  edge swipe using this function:

```
animateAlongsideTransitionInView:animation:completion
```

But for this I need to get superview of the keyboard. So I was adding one dummy inputAccesoryView to it and then using it to get superview. But I do not want to use this method as this seems very brittle. Is there anyway to get reference to directly keyboard or its superview without using inputAccesoryView.
Any help will be appreciated as I am stuck badly on this. Have searched a lot but everywhere it is written to use this inputAccessory method.